# JPA reserved keywords to postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm using JPA with a postgres DBMS and I'm trying to create a new entity that maps to the table "User".

This is a very common problem as User is a reserved word in Postgres. My question is, how can i "escape" the reserved keyword or set JPA to escape it?

I tried @Table(name = "\"user\"") with no luck:

> 2009-02-25 15:43:14,218 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: create table "User"_Module (users_login varchar(100) not null, modules_id int8 not null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
@Table(name = "`user`")
```

and it works...

Comment: This does not help me as entities referencing the User entity need to have a column called "user" and then it breaks again. With simple entities I can escape the column name again, but not with collections of embedables...